# Remove Ownership of data pointer in GstBuffer

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

My current use case is that I am trying to give GStreamer an existing pointer to an input image and let it run through the pipeline. After the gstreamer pipeline completes, I want GstBuffer to give up ownership of the input pointer I gave it and let me manage it again and for GstBuffer to cleanup its own class. I currently use GStreamer to do image format conversion. For example from RGB -> BGR.

Currently, I do:

```
GstBuffer * buffer = gst_buffer_new_wrapped_full( (GstMemoryFlags)0, (gpointer)(indata), insize, 0, insize, NULL, NULL );
gst_buffer_ref(buffer);
gst_app_src_push_buffer(GST_APP_SRC(appSrc), buffer);
```

But I am having trouble figuring out how to let GstBuffer let go of the pointer I gave it.

Comment: Isn't the `GDestroyNotify` parameter of `gst_buffer_new_wrapped_full` what you are looking for? E.g. don't free the buffer, but mark it as re-usable instead somehow.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch The documentation states `When the buffer is destroyed, notify will be called with user_data`. I don't think that's what I want. I want to basically tell GstBuffer "Don't delete the data Ptr you were given in the function gst_buffer_new_wrapped_full but cleanup the GstBuffer class". I was trying ways of modifying the GstBuffer to null out the size and ptr manually so it cleans up nothing by modifying the pointer after I call `gst_buffer_map`, but that did not work.

Comment: I thought it may assign you the task to delete it yourself (or in your case skip that step). But I guess if that doesn't do it I feel like `GstAllocator` is the way to go.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch, Thanks! I think that's what I want but it's so hard to find good examples for it. I think I just need to play around with it for a few hours.

Comment: It's still not clear to me. passing a destroy notify of NULL will prevent Gstreamer from freeing the pointer. Isn't that what you were looking for?